# What does the term "Fury Road" mean in-universe?

Tags: mad-max-fury-road

During the confrontation between Nux and his lancer Slit, Nux forbids him to take his wheel and drive.  Slit points out that, if Nux can't stand up, he can't do war.  Nux retorts with a headbutt, and says:

```
 "If I'm gonna die, I'm gonna die historic on the Fury Road."
```

**"Fury Road" is a term that has an in-universe meaning.  What is that meaning?**
Is it a term for a battle on the move?  Is is the name for the specific route Furiosa took, and they are about to follow?  Is it their general term for the less-than-kind outside world?  Is it something else?

Answer (score 7):

There are no definitive answers from Miller regarding "Fury Road" as an actual location, so we have to look for symbolic references.  Nux refers to it as "the Fury Road" as if the name is very spiritual. One could assume this is the path that the Warboys follow to Valhalla. To die historic you must die on the Fury Road. This is why he won't relinquish his wheel and die quietly in town. He must follow the Fury Road.